# Pylint Error when using metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, pylint, syntastic

i try to fix all pylint errors and pylint warnings in a project. but i keep getting an error when i set a metaclass (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/).

here is my example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class MyMeta(type):
    pass

class MyObject(object, metaclass=MyMeta): # pylint error here
    pass
```

the error just says "invalid syntax". i use pylint via the vim plugin syntastic (https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic).

my pylint version is (pylint --version):

```
pylint 1.4.3, 
astroid 1.3.6, common 0.63.2
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1]
```

my syntastic plugin is up to date with github.

any ideas?

Comment: Are you using pylint for python2? The docs suggest `let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = '/path/to/python3'`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham:  Please convert your comment to an answer so we can vote it up!  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [docs](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) under *4.2. Q. The python checker complains about syntactically valid Python 3 constructs...*:

> A. Configure the python checker to call a Python 3 interpreter rather than Python 2, e.g:

```
let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = '/path/to/python3'
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'll be able to find it when it happens to me.  ;)